# Python on OSX 10.11: Installation failed - no software found to install

Tags: python, osx-elcapitan, python-3.2

Starting a Python course via Udemy. Trying to install Python 3.2.3 (used in course) 64-bit on OSX 10.11.1, but running the dmg produces a msg saying the installation failed as it could not find the software to install. What goes wrong? Have installed python previously (other versions and on earlier OSX-version), and have never encountered this problem. Any suggestions re how to get around this?

[picture of installation failure message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uMpt.png)

Comment: A little more of context

Comment: Maybe try using homebrew? I've upgraded to El capitan, so I know python3 works. Not sure what that error means

Comment: Just use Enthought Canopy or Anaconda - it'll save you a lot of headaches in particular when installing some of the scientific packages.

Comment: Thank you. I did install Canopy. Bypasses the problem, but does not solve it.